# Using pipes in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Writing script in AWK - input data - time in format `31.12.2012`. I want to compare 2 dates - system date and this date. I think the best way is to convert both dates into unix timestamp, make deduction and then compare with conditional. Date can be converted into unix timestamp only with this format `2012-12-31` . To convert into this format I write SED expression `sed -n -e "s_\(..\)\(.\)\(..\)\(.\)\(....\)_\5-\3-\1_p"`. And then we must convert this expression with command `date --utc --date "2012-12-31" +%s`. But pipes doesnt want to work.

In the AWK i wrote:

---

```
#/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=",";
}
{
    split($3, account, "/");
    gsub(/ $/, "", account[1]);
    split($4, products, "\\\\n");
    split($5, supports, "\\\\n");
    for (i in products) {
        gsub("\"", "", products[i]);
        gsub("\"", "", supports[i]);
        split(supports[i], timesupport, "\ > ");
        "date +%s" | getline dateVal;
        print timesupport[1] | sed -n -e "s_\(..\)\(.\)\(..\)\(.\)\(....\)_\5-\3-\1_p" | getline timeVal1 | date --utc --date "timeVal1" +%s | getline timeVal;
        x=dateVal - timeVal;
        if (supports[i] !~ /n\\\\a*/ && supports[i] !~ /n\/a*/ && $2 !~ /\NULL/)
            print $1","$2","timesupport[1]","account[1]"\","products[i]"\","$6;

    }
}
```

The main thread was in post 12634588. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the builtin time functions:

```
(echo | awk '{ print systime() }'; date +%s)
1348915323                
1348915323
```

To convert the string you mentioned to the same format, use `mktime`:

```awk
{ 
  t = "31.12.2012"
  split(t, a, "\\.")
  ts = sprintf("%04d %02d %02d 00 00 00", a[3], a[2], a[1])
  print mktime(ts)
}
```

Output:

```
1356908400
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to mix bash and awk code.  Try using the system() call to execute code in bash and returning the results within awk.

Answer (score 1):

The `system()` function and the `getline` command actually pass their argument to `/bin/sh`. This allows you you to use pipes as you would in the shell. Example:

```
cmd = sprintf("echo '%s' | sed -e '...'", timesupport[1])
cmd | getline timeval
```

Your question doesn't make it exactly clear what the input to the script is, so I can't give you a more relevant example.